# Ecto changeset validates only one association per time

Tags: validation, elixir, ecto

Could someone help me understand how changeset validation works with associations in order to show all changeset association errors at once?

I’ve create some example below to explain.

Notice that if a `Post` have a invalid changeset but also its `Comment/Like` associated changesets are supposed to be invalid too, the result changeset only validated the Post attributes:

```
Post.create_changeset(%Post{}, %{title: ""})
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:comments, comments_changeset)
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:likes, likes_changeset)
|> Repo.insert

#ecto.Changeset<action: :insert,
 changes: %{
   comments: [#ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{text: nil}, errors: [], data: #Comment<>, valid?: true>],
   likes: [#ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{up: nil}, errors: [], data: #Like<>, valid?: true>]
 },
 errors: [title: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
 data: #Post<>, valid?: false>
```

Otherwise, when the post is fulfilled with title and it's valid, now the result changeset shows errors from the associated `Comment`, but not with the Like.

```
Post.create_changeset(%Post{}, %{title: "now i have a title"})
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:comments, comments_changeset)
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:likes, likes_changeset)
|> Repo.insert

#ecto.Changeset<action: :insert,
 changes: %{
   comments: [#ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{text: nil}, errors: [title: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}], data: #Comment<>, valid?: false>],
   likes: [#ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{up: nil}, errors: [], data: #Like<>, valid?: true>]
 },
 errors: [], data: #Post<>, valid?: false>
```

It behaves as some kind of "lazy validation". Is this expected to be like this in Ecto?

Comment: How do the `comments_changeset` and `likes_changeset` look like beofre assembling everything together? All the errors should already be there. Also - how do you access all the errors? Are you using `Ecto.Changeset.traverse_errors`?

Comment: I don't mean to be disrespectful... but how can you troubleshoot a validation error without looking at the changeset implementation? Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: @michalmuskala Just figured out that my original code has a relevant difference that I didn't notice. My associations changesets are many-to-many tables and their changeset validations are `foreign_key_constraint`. And early today I realized that an error in thing changeset is pushed to the response changeset after it goes down to the database level. So it probably rollsback on the first association and return. I guess the only way to have all these errors are to make these foreign key constraints manually outside changeset and using a `Repo.find` to check. Is that correct? Thanks